# How to create a dynamic lambda expression based on two models?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes.

```
public class First
{
public int P {get; set;}
public int A {get; set;}
public int B {get; set;}
}
public class Second
{
public int P {get; set;}
public int C {get; set;}
}
```

I want to calculate something like this.

```
var first = A collection of First,
var second = A collection of Second

first.Select(f=> f.A * second.FirstOrDefault(s => s.P == f.P).C).Sum();
```

I can change f=> f.A in an expression using ()

```
ParameterExpression f =  Expression.Parameter(typeof(First), 'f');
Expression a = Expression.Property(f, "A");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(Func<First, decimal>(a, f));
lambda.Complie()
```

I tried to change s => s.P == f.P in an expression using // internal lambda

```
ParameterExpression f =  Expression.Parameter(typeof(First), 'f');
ParameterExpression s =  Expression.Parameter(typeof(Second), 's');
Expression fp = Expression.Property(f, "P");
Expression sp = Expression.Property(s, "P");
Expression finalExp = Expression.Equal(sp, fp);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(Func<Second, bool>(finalExp , s));
lambda.Complie()
```

I faced two issues in this code.

1. Internal lambda code fails at lambda.Complie(). Error: - system linq expression variable 'f' of type 'First' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined.
2. In  first.Select(f=> f.A * second.FirstOrDefault(s => s.P == f.P).C), f=> f.A is an expression and the other part is a decimal, so can't multiply.

Comment: The expression `second.FirstOrDefault(s => s.P == f.P)` cannot be compiled on its own - it has no reference to `f`. You need to use it from the body of the outer expression, and only compile the outer expression.

Comment: Understood that internal lambda has no reference for f. May you please write a code or pseudo code snippet?

Comment: Why do you need to use an `Expression` tree? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need generic method for handling such expressions:

```cs
public static int CalcSum<TFirst, TSecond>(IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second)
{
    var f = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirst), "f");
    var s = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSecond), "s"); 

    var firstQueryable = first.AsQueryable();
    var secondQueryable = second.AsQueryable();

    // s => f.P == s.P
    var firstOrDefaultFilter = Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(f, "P"), Expression.Property(s, "P")),
        s);

    // second.FirstOrDefault(f.P == s.P)
    var firstOrDefault = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.FirstOrDefault),
        new[] { typeof(TSecond) }, secondQueryable.Expression, firstOrDefaultFilter);

    // second.FirstOrDefault(f.P == s.P).C
    var propertyToSum = Expression.Property(firstOrDefault, "C");

    // f => f.A * second.FirstOrDefault(f.P == s.P).C
    var selectLambda = Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Multiply(Expression.Property(f, "A"), propertyToSum),
        f);

    // first.Select(f => f.A * second.FirstOrDefault(f.P == s.P).C)
    var queryExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Select),
        new Type[] { typeof(TFirst), typeof(int) }, firstQueryable.Expression, selectLambda);

    var query = firstQueryable.Provider.CreateQuery<int>(queryExpr);

    return query.Sum();
}
```